# Is there a topologically mixing and minimal homeomorphism on the circle (or on $\mathbb S^2$)?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, topological-dynamics

The irrational rotation on the circle is both a homeomorphism and minimal but is not topologically mixing. The argument-doubling transformation on the circle is topologically mixing but is neither a homeomorphism nor is it minimal.

Is there a topologically mixing and minimal homeomorphism on the circle (or on $\mathbb S^2$)?

Comment: Topologically mixing: for all nonempty open subsets $A,B$, there exists $N$ such that for every $n\ge N$ we have $f^n(A)\cap B\neq\emptyset$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_(mathematics)#Topological_mixing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no topologically mixing self-homeomorphism of the circle. Indeed, pick 3 points, so that the complement of these 3 points consists of 3 intervals $A,B,C$. If $g$ is a self-homeomorphism such that $g(A)$ meets all of $A,B,C$, then it has to contain entirely one of $A,B,C$.

Therefore it is not possible that all the intersections $g(A)\cap A$, $g(A)\cap B$, $g(A)\cap C$, $g(B)\cap A$, $g(B)\cap B$, $g(B)\cap C$ be simultaneously nonempty. (If $f$ were a topologically mixing self-homeomorphism, $f^n$ for large $n$ would have to satisfy this property.)

On $S^2$ it's completely another question.

Comment: This argument should work also for weakly mixing minimal homeomorphisms of the circle. Indeed, by a theorem of Furstenberg, weak mixing implies weak mixing of all orders. Thus $f^n(A)\times f^n(A)\times f^n(A)\times f^n(B)\times f^n(B)\times f^n(B) \cap A\times B\times C\times A\times B\times C \not= \emptyset$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is the same consequence of mixing used in YCor's argument.

Answer (score 4):

By Lefschetz fixed point theorem, any continuous map $f\colon\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{S}^2$ has a fixed point. So, there is no hope of getting any minimal homeomorphism on $\mathbb{S}^2$.

However, there exist minimal mixing homeomorphisms on the $2$-torus. The first examples were constructed by A. Kochergin in http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM2002v193n03ABEH000636 and more recently Artur Avila has announced the existence of smooth minimal and mixing diffeomorphisms.

Comment: I mentioned the first fact in a comment to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/253156/ (more precisely $f^2$ has a fixed point! antipodal map has no fixed point). But this does not mean there's no topologically mixing self-homeomorphism of the 2-sphere (at least, there are topologically transitive self-homeomorphisms, which is not trivial).

Comment: @YCor, if minimality is not required, then it does exist area-preserving diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{S}^2$ which are in fact mixing (not just topologically mixing). Some examples can be found in the paper of Katok https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971237?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents