# Existence of topologically mixing (discrete) dynamical system on manifold

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology, mixing

If $M$ is a connected $(d\geq 2)$-dimensional smooth closed manifold, then does there exist a class $C^1$-diffeomorphism $\phi$ from $M$ onto itself, such that $(M,\phi)$ is a topologically mixing (discrete) dynamical system?

Comment: True, I really only need a $C^1$-structure on the manifold.

Comment: This is answered (negatively) [at this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252959/is-there-a-topologically-mixing-and-minimal-homeomorphism-on-the-circle-or-on) for $d=1$.

Comment: I forgot to put $d\geq 2$ (this seems possible since I know any compact manifold of dimension $d\geq 2$) admits a topologically transitive map.

Comment: OK. In a comment to [another answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/253166/14094) to that same linked question, it is said that the answer is yes for the 2-sphere (which can sound surprising).

Comment: Ah, so there is hope that it is true in general... but is this the case then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's true.

It follows from a result of Abdenur and Crovisier ([ArXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4206)) [AC]: given a volume form $\omega$ on $M$ (closed manifold — the authors seem to omit assuming $\dim(M)\neq 1$), inside the topological group $\mathrm{Diff}^1(M,\omega)\subset\mathrm{Diff}^1(M)$, there is a Baire-generic subset of topologically mixing elements.

Note that it's not true in dimension 1 since then $\mathrm{Diff}^1(M,\omega)$ is reduced to the group of isometries (of some metric canonically determined by $\omega$, isometric to the standard circle), and actually there's no topologically mixing self-homeomorphism at all ([see this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/252965/14094)).

Also, in the whole group $\mathrm{Diff}^1(M)$, the set of topologically mixing elements is not dense at all. Indeed, choose two small disjoint open subsets $U,V$ and $f$ with $f(\bar{U})\subset U$: then any close neighbor $g$ of $f$ (in the $C^0$, hence in the $C^1$ topology) satisfies $g(\bar{U})\subset U$ hence $g^n(U)\cap V$ empty for all $n\ge 0$, hence $g$ fails to be mixing.

[AC] F. Abdenur, S. Crovisier, *Transitivity and topological mixing for C1 diffeomorphisms. Essays in mathematics and its applications, 1–16, Springer, Heidelberg, 2012.*

Comment: This is an amazing answer.  Thanks YCor :)